# How to add listener for item click in MaterialSearchView

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, searchview, onitemclicklistener

How to add listener for item click in MaterialSearchView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grids);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        locationStatus =sharedPreferences.getString(locationStatus,"");
searchView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String s=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

I tried this code but item click listener is not working

Comment: the setOnItemClickListener is fired when you click in one item.

Comment: nothing is been fired that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I do have  a problem like this before, and I find out the soulution from [this guys](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView)

Long short story I just put this on my code

> searchView.setSubmitOnClick(true);

and it'll submit the sugestion text as query or you can add this to get the listener

```
searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSearchViewShown() {
        //Do some magic
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchViewClosed() {

    }
});
```